# Python3 Multithreading?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand multi-threading in python3. Does **python3** support **multithreading**? Yes/No. Core Python packages/library used for multi-threading not the **3rd party**, and difference between multithreading and multiprocessing.

Comment: Multiprocessing? https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: @FedericoBaù: That's not multi-*threading*, though it's often useful as a replacement for it.

Comment: " though it's often useful as a replacement for it."  That's excatly why I added it.

Comment: @Samwise thanks for your time, i google but ... https://www.quora.com/Why-does-Python-not-support-multithreading

Answer (score 1):

Obviously yes. That's what the `threading` and `concurrent.futures` built-in modules are for (the latter also supports multi-process processing, as does `multiprocessing`). That said, CPython still has a [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GIL), so without third-party packages involved (or use of multi-process techniques), you'll only see benefits from threading on I/O bound tasks; CPU bound threads will only run one at a time.